# Create a widget that allows text input

Tags: widgets

I need to create a simple widget that has a text input field.

I need the widget to create the markup below...

```
<div class="textwidget">
    <div class="avatar"> 
        <div class="avatartext"> 
            <p>CONTENTS OF THE TEXT INPUT HERE</p>
        </div> 
    <div class="avatarimage"></div> 
</div>
```

I've started the process of stubbing out the widget with the code below. I'm just not shure how to code the my_avatar() function...

```
function my_avatar()
{
//Widget markup goes here. How to pull the widget text entry?

}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'my_avatar');

class My_Widget_Avatar extends WP_Widget {
    function My_Widget_Avatar() {
        $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'widget_avatar', 'description' => __( "My Avatar Widget" ) );
        $this->WP_Widget('my_avatar', __('My Avatar'), $widget_ops);
    }
}

add_action('widgets_init', create_function('', "register_widget('My_Widget_Avatar');"));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Complete code:

```
class My_Widget_Avatar extends WP_Widget {
    function My_Widget_Avatar() {
        $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'widget_avatar', 'description' => __( "My Avatar Widget" ) );
        $this->WP_Widget('my_avatar', __('My Avatar'), $widget_ops);
    }

    function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        extract($args);
        $text = apply_filters( 'widget_text', $instance['text'], $instance );
        echo $before_widget;
        ?>
            <div class="textwidget">
                <div class="avatar"> 
                    <div class="avatartext">
                        <p><?php echo $text; ?></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="avatarimage"></div> 
            </div> 
        <?php
        echo $after_widget;
    }

    function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = $old_instance;
        if ( current_user_can('unfiltered_html') )
            $instance['text'] =  $new_instance['text'];
        else
            $instance['text'] = stripslashes( wp_filter_post_kses( addslashes($new_instance['text']) ) ); // wp_filter_post_kses() expects slashed
        return $instance;
    }

    function form( $instance ) {
        $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, array( 'text' => '' ) );
        $text = format_to_edit($instance['text']);
?>

        <textarea class="widefat" rows="16" cols="20" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('text'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('text'); ?>"><?php echo $text; ?></textarea>
<?php
    }
}


function lbi_widgets_init() {
    register_widget( 'My_Widget_Avatar' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'lbi_widgets_init' );
```

Comment: Wow, thanks Sorich. Great job. Only problem I found is that the container div (widget_avatar) is missing its closing div tag. Where should I add that in your code?

Comment: sorich, how would I change your code if I don't want to offer a Title entry?

Comment: I edited my answer and removed the Title entry. I also added the missing div (it is missing in the output markup you provided).